# python3 mysqldb mysql's "connect" command not working

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I want to connect and create a database in mysql from python (3).
So I use something like this:

```
import MySQLdb
con=MySQLdb.connect (host = "192.168.1.2", user = "root",passwd = "pouetpouet")
-- Ok. I'm connected without choosing a database. 
cur=con.cursor (MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
con.autocommit(True)
cur.execute("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS MyNewBase") ## ok
cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE MyNewBase") ## ok 
cur.execute("CONNECT MyNewBase") ## Fail !!! why ?
```

> ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONNECT MyNewBase' at line 1")`

After checking on directly on server, MyNewBase is correctly created. 
Doing the same steps in mysql shell works well.

Comment: Its `USE MyNewBase`.